# Firebase retrieve single value in child loop

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm retrieving a few items from Firebase using `.ChildAdded` when I print the child  in the loop I see all the keys and values and they all start with snap problem is when I go head and `print(child.value["myKeyhere"])` I get a system error. How can I solve this

Firebase child result print from loop * I want to retrieve 'age' only*

```
    Snap (age) 54
    Snap (email) User1@gmail.com
    Snap (firstname) User2Firstname
    Snap (lastname) User2Lastname
    Snap (profilePic) users/profilePhoto/fKNTGRGfmgdZwtHUyJxOjnKXZzx2.jpg
    Snap (receivePostRequest) {
        lat = "37.32550194";
        long = "-122.01974475";
        status = 1;
        tags =     {
            beauty = 0;
            heathcare = 0;
            house = 1;
            housekeeper = 0;
            scholar = 0;
            student = 0;
        };
    }
```

my code

```
let dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        dbref.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("receivePostRequest/status").queryEqualToValue(true).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

            var helprInfo = [[String: AnyObject]]()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                   print(child)




            }
        })
```

Comment: try to use `snapshot.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

child.value["myKeyhere"]as! String